# How to toggle background between two buttons in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I created an app with two buttons. What I want is when the left button is clicked, it will change it's background color. If the right button is clicked, change that background color.

Above concept is working with the following code for both buttons:

```
 @IBAction func pressedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        sender.backgroundColor = (sender.backgroundColor == Constants.BOOL_BUTTON.enabled) ? Constants.BOOL_BUTTON.disabled : Constants.BOOL_BUTTON.enabled

    }
```

Both buttons are linked to this function. The only thing what is not working, is that when the left button for example had the enabled color and the user then clicks on the right button to change his choice, the left button will not be resetting to it's disabled color. How can I achieve this with above function?

Comment: Check the `sender` if it's the first or second button (keep an IBOutlet/var on them). Then "invert" them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is when right or left button is pressed, it doesn't know about the state of the other one. What you can do is:

```
@IBAction func pressedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
  if sender.backgroundColor == Constants.BOOL_BUTTON.enabled {
    return
  }
  sender.backgroundColor = Constants.BOOL_BUTTON.enabled

  switch sender {
  case self.leftButton:
    self.rightButton.backgroundColor = Constants.BOOL_BUTTON.disabled

  case self.rightButton:
    self.leftButton.backgroundColor = Constants.BOOL_BUTTON.disabled

  default:
    return
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible when you clicked for example the left button, that when you click the second time, nothing Is happening. Now it will activate the right button.. and visa versa.

Comment: @Caspert you can check the background color and if it's the enabled one, then you simply do nothing. Updated the code.

Comment: Thanks, awesome that you helped me!